# Space of real matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the set (where $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$)

\begin{bmatrix}
       x & 0 & y           \\[0.3em]
       0 & x-y           & x+z \\[0.3em]
       y           & x-z & x
     \end{bmatrix}

is a vector space in the space of matrices $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and calculate its dimension.

I know how to solve this type of problem when the space is $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, but I don't know how to even begin here.

This is not part of the problem, but could someone find a basis for this set too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
       x & 0 & y           \\[0.3em]
       0 & x-y           & x+z \\[0.3em]
       y           & x-z & x
     \end{bmatrix}=x \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0 & 0           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1           & 1 \\[0.3em]
       0           & 1 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}+y \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 & 1           \\[0.3em]
       0 & -1           & 0 \\[0.3em]
       1          & 0 & 1
     \end{bmatrix}+z \begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 & 0           \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0           & 1 \\[0.3em]
       0          & -1 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}\\
=xA+yB+zC$$
So the given set is spanned by $A,B$ and $C$. Verify that the vectors $(A,B,C)$ are linearly independent and conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to show it's a vector space, the only operations you need to consider are matrix addition and scalar multiplication.  Those are exactly the same as if you rearrange the entries in the matrix into a $9\times1$ vector:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
0\\
y\\
0\\
x-y\\
x-z\\
y\\
x+z\\
x
\end{pmatrix}
$$

You can even define the inner (dot) product on this space: $A.B:=\textrm{tr}(A^TB)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ by setting the basis $e_{ij}=$ the matrix with zero everywhere except for a $1$ in position $ij$. You can then use this to calculate the dimension of your vector space. Or you can notice that you have $3$ free (independent) parameters, and thus the dimension is $3$.

To check it is really a vector space, you can work directly on your matrices. Simply show that the axioms for a vector space hold. Sum is given by sum of matrices, and scalar multiplication is $\lambda (M_{ij}) = (\lambda M_{ij})$.